# Sorting column with blanks in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have an excel file with item-code and quantity year wise sale (i.e1718Sale)  for the entire factory. The sheets in not uni-formal data for sorting. I want to put blank in the quatity for the year if there is no sale in that year. So that while sorting I would find what is the sale value for each code in the years.

I am not having knowledge in the VBA and applied lot of if, match formulas but couldn't find any solution. Can any one help me please.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without any example of result, why do you need to sort? Perhaps countif(), countifs() etc will be sufficient. Also checkout averageif() averageifs() etc

Comment: My point is to keep one code row (by deleting another two rows of code) and simplifying the excel sheet to look-like  the Header as: **CODE, 1718 QTY, 1819QTY,1919 QTY**

Comment: So you can do two things now: 1) improve your question with a clear expected input and ouput along with showing the code you have so far and 2) investigate the use of countif() countifs() sumif() and sumifs()

Comment: I have mentioned the the Out put to be in single

Comment: If cell.value=0 then cell.value=""

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formula solution

In `A13`, array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(TEXT(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($2:$9)/1%+COLUMN($A:$G)/(COUNTIF(A$2:G$9,"<"&A$2:G$9)+1-SUM(COUNTIF(A$12:A12,A$2:G$9))=1)/(A$1:G$1=A$12),1),"r0c00"),0),"")
```

In `B13`, formula copied across right to `D13` and all copied down :

```
=IF($A13="","",IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A13,CHOOSE(LEFT(B$12,2)-16,$A$2:$B$9,$D$2:$E$9,$G$2:$H$9),2,0),0))
```

[image]